# Xdebug breakpoint not working for Laravel

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I am having issue hitting breakpoint in Laravel Code. I am using Windows + VSCode + XAMPP + Xdebug + Xdebughelper (Chrome plugin)

Currently I have no file mapping config in VScode (launch.json) and breakpoint is working fine for `C:\xampp\htdocs\company\project_name\public\index.php`,

But its not working for any other code like controller or views etc. e.g. `C:\xampp\htdocs\company\project_name\resources\views\auth\login`

I tried setting path mapping, but its not working for me.